# express.js file not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to express/node.js and I am having trouble finding the page at localhost:3000/info

The images of my code are linked below

[image: app.js]

[image: index.js]

Comment: how do you run the app ? what are the errors ?

Comment: I use npm start to run it and it gives me a 404 when I try to go to localhost:3000/info but localhost:3000 gives me "/" and the rendered page

Comment: do you have a route for `info`?

Comment: I am sort of new to express and I actually don't know. How do I create one?

Comment: Sorry. i saw that you have a `info` route in the index.js at line 10

Comment: can i see the command line output ?

Comment: Should line 10 read as router.get('/info') instead of just router.get('info') ?

Comment: yea that was the problem, it should be ('/info').Now I got more errors from mongodb now. But thank you.

Comment: Add code as text to you question and not using images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you indeed create a route for the info page, but as far as I can see in the images you never tell express to use that route...

```
var infoRouter = require=('./routes/info');


app.use(inforRouter);
```

The first line is for loading the module, and the second one is for its execution